# Bash: per-login environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Is there a way to have an environment variable, or some similar construct, persist across all bash terminal instances in any given login session?

What I'm trying to do is have a variable prompt, which I can switch (for all terminal windows, future, and maybe also current) at a whim. The process of switching is not too important, but I'd like for it to be a set-and-forget thing.

So far, the best option seems to be to have a set of hardcoded values in .bashrc, which my 'switcher' script would edit, but that seems a bit hacky, and prone to destroying everything if there are any minor errors.

Comment: Please define 'bash terminal instances' and 'login session', and how you start these shells.

Comment: You can't change the environment of an already started process. You could make bashrc load a variable from a third location (set by a file or the environment), then use it while setting the prompt.

Comment: You can `source` your `PS1` variable from a separate file in your `.bashrc` and you can change the value for `PS1` and then source it again in the running shell. That way your switcher could be a *function* or *alias*.

Comment: Why do you need this?  I'm not saying you don't need it, but if we know the reason we might be able to suggest an alternative..

Comment: @JuliePelletier, I'm not entirely sure what the proper names are, but 'bash terminal instances' are instances (windows) of my terminal emulator; and 'login sessions' are whatever starts when you log in, and ends when you log out, of a given user account.

Comment: @cdarke, I'm just mildly fickle. Some days I'll want my terminal to prompt me with the time, in black and white; other days, I want a prompt to ask me `yes, zoey?` before each command, in pink or something. If I could set it at the start of the day, rather than per terminal, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the easiest solution: Write the data to a file instead of a variable.

You can also create some helpers in your .bashrc to automatically retrieve/set the value. A file seems to fulfil all your requirements.

EDIT: You can also have the helpers set the variable on each login from the file.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to change the prompt in *every* active shell at once, but you can define functions to your `.bashrc` which you can call to change the prompt at will.

```
use_prompt_1 () {
    PS1="\w \$"
}

use_prompt_2 () {
    PS1="\u@\h \$"
}
```

You can also use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to examine your environment to choose a prompt. Add something like the following to your `.bashrc` as well:

```
dynamic_prompt () {
    if [[ $PWD =~ some_regex ]]; then
        use_prompt_1
    else
        use_prompt_2
    fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=dynamic_prompt
```

Comment: You could change a file and then in `PROMPT_COMMAND` check that file for changes if any, use them as prompt. This way you could "change" the prompt for all active terminals at once.

Comment: That's a good idea. I was trying to figure out if there was a signal-based solution, but a file would be simpler.

Comment: Tell me if you get something going with signals, would be interesting :-)